# 'sed: no input files' when using sed -i in a loop

Tags: bash, loops, csv, sed

I checked some solutions for this in other questions, but they are not working with my case and I'm stuck so here we go.
I have a csv file that I want to convert all to uppercase. It has to be with a loop and occupate 7 lines of code minimum. I have to run the script with this command:

```
./c_bash.sh student-mat.csv
```

So I tried this Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i c=0
while read -r line; do 
    if [ "$c" -gt '0' ]; then 
       sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'      
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
    ((c++))
done < student-mat.csv
```

I know that maybe there are a couple of unnecessary things on it, but I want to focus in the sed command because it looks like the problem here.
That script shows this output:(first 5 lines):

```
school,sex,age,address,famsize,Pstatus,Medu,Fedu,Mjob,Fjob,reason,guardian,traveltime,studytime,failures,schoolsup,famsup,paid,activities,nursery,higher,internet,romantic,famrel,freetime,goout,Dalc,Walc,health,absences,G1,G2,G3
GP,F,17,U,GT3,T,1,1,AT_HOME,OTHER,COURSE,FATHER,1,2,0,NO,YES,NO,NO,NO,YES,YES,NO,5,3,3,1,1,3,4,5,5,6
GP,F,15,U,LE3,T,1,1,AT_HOME,OTHER,OTHER,MOTHER,1,2,3,YES,NO,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,NO,4,3,2,2,3,3,10,7,8,10
GP,F,15,U,GT3,T,4,2,HEALTH,SERVICES,HOME,MOTHER,1,3,0,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,3,2,2,1,1,5,2,15,14,15
GP,F,16,U,GT3,T,3,3,OTHER,OTHER,HOME,FATHER,1,2,0,NO,YES,YES,NO,YES,YES,NO,NO,4,3,2,1,2,5,4,6,10,10
GP,M,16,U,LE3,T,4,3,SERVICES,OTHER,REPUTATION,MOTHER,1,2,0,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,5,4,2,1,2,5,10,15,15,15
```

Now that I see that it works, I want to apply that sed command permanently to the csv file, so I put -i after it:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i c=0
while read -r line; do 
    if [ "$c" -gt '0' ]; then 
       sed -i -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'      
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
    ((c++))
done < student-mat.csv
```

But the output instead of applying the changes, shows this:(first 5 lines)

```
school,sex,age,address,famsize,Pstatus,Medu,Fedu,Mjob,Fjob,reason,guardian,traveltime,studytime,failures,schoolsup,famsup,paid,activities,nursery,higher,internet,romantic,famrel,freetime,goout,Dalc,Walc,health,absences,G1,G2,G3
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
sed: no input files
```

So checking a lot of different solutions on the internet, I also tried to change single quoting to double quoting.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -i c=0
while read -r line; do 
    if [ "$c" -gt '0' ]; then 
       sed -i -e "s/\(.*\)/\U\1/"       
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
    ((c++))
done < student-mat.csv
```

But in this case, instead of applying the changes, it generate a file with 0 bytes. So no output when I do this:

```
cat student-mat.csv
```

My expected solution here is that, when I apply this script, it changes permanently all the data to uppercase. And after applying the script, it should show this with the command cat student-mat.csv: (first 5 lines)

```
school,sex,age,address,famsize,Pstatus,Medu,Fedu,Mjob,Fjob,reason,guardian,traveltime,studytime,failures,schoolsup,famsup,paid,activities,nursery,higher,internet,romantic,famrel,freetime,goout,Dalc,Walc,health,absences,G1,G2,G3
GP,F,17,U,GT3,T,1,1,AT_HOME,OTHER,COURSE,FATHER,1,2,0,NO,YES,NO,NO,NO,YES,YES,NO,5,3,3,1,1,3,4,5,5,6
GP,F,15,U,LE3,T,1,1,AT_HOME,OTHER,OTHER,MOTHER,1,2,3,YES,NO,YES,NO,YES,YES,YES,NO,4,3,2,2,3,3,10,7,8,10
GP,F,15,U,GT3,T,4,2,HEALTH,SERVICES,HOME,MOTHER,1,3,0,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,3,2,2,1,1,5,2,15,14,15
GP,F,16,U,GT3,T,3,3,OTHER,OTHER,HOME,FATHER,1,2,0,NO,YES,YES,NO,YES,YES,NO,NO,4,3,2,1,2,5,4,6,10,10
GP,M,16,U,LE3,T,4,3,SERVICES,OTHER,REPUTATION,MOTHER,1,2,0,NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,5,4,2,1,2,5,10,15,15,15
```

Comment: Are you sure your code modifies second line?

Comment: You said the solution `has to be with a loop and occupate 7 lines of code minimum` but accepted an answer that, though a good way to transform the data as you want, doesn't use a loop and is only 1 line. Please make sure to correctly state your requirements when posting questions so we can help you get the solution you actually need.

Comment: @EdMorton The problem was with the sed line, so they gave me a solution about that line. So I changed my sed line for that one and it worked. The rest of my code will be untouched, so it mantains the loop and the 7 lines. That's why I considered it the correct solution.

Comment: The sed command in the answer will make all of the changes to all of the lines in your input all at one time. Every other line in your script can (and should) be deleted and it won't change anything about the outcome. Every call to sed after the first will do nothing as all letters will already be upper case by then. If this is homework and your teacher wants an answer that requires 7 lines of code - this is 100% NOT the 7 lines they are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sed works *on files*, not on lines. Do not read lines, use sed on the file. Sed can exclude the first line by itself. See sed manual.

You want:

```
sed -i -e '2,$s/\(.*\)/\U\1/' student-mat.csv
```

You can do shorter with `s/.*/\U&/`.

---

Your code does not work as you think it does. Note that your code *removes the second line* from the output. Your code:

- reads first line with `read -r line`
- `echo "$line"` first line is printed
- `c++` is incremented
- `read -r line` reads second line
- then `sed` *processes the rest of the file* (from line 3 till the end) and prints them in upper case
- then `c++` is incremented
- then `read -r line` fails, and the loop exits